# Mouse polling rate too high

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, mouse, logitech-mouse

I have usb mouse logitech mx518 and I use tweaked windows xp sp3 for gaming . I like all tweaks in it except one issue 
Mouse or (usb) polling rate :

Because of this problem I hear noise in my headphone and the tone changes when I move the mouse

That's screen recording (gif file) of what I mean

[image]

**note :** I get this on usb ports only usb 2.0 (125Hz)

I used to have constant 1000 Hz , in previous installation and mouse was feeling good and useful

Any suggestion to solve this problem (I know the solution of reinstall windows and upgrade)?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1000hz? Gee whiz! Quake player or something?

It seems really silly, but a user in the link below seems to have fixed the issue but regularly running disk defragmenter

https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?7046-G53SW-1000HZ-polling-rate-on-mouse-cause-high-pitched-noise

Comment: so silly, it is beyond belief

Comment: It might as well as be magic at that point XD